# I am having one problem temperature sensor in Raspberry Pi3

Tags: temperature

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/iot $ sudo modprobe w1-gpio
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/iot $ sudo modprobe w1-therm
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/iot $ cd /sys/bus/w1/devices
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices $ ls
00-280000000000  00-c80000000000  w1_bus_master1
pi@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices $ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 21 06:51 00-280000000000 -> ../../../devices/w1_bus_master1/00-280000000000
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 May 21 06:37 w1_bus_master1 -> ../../../devices/w1_bus_master1


pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/iot $ sudo python 7_temperature.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "7_temperature.py", line 9, in <module>
    device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: After editing your post so a human can read it, I see the line `base_dir + '28*'` ... there's nothing in the folder with the name starting with `28*` - perhaps it should be `00-28*`

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** DS18B20 connected to the 1-wire bus.

You should be using device tree now rather than modprobing.  See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.

**When** you connect the DS18B20 correctly the following code will give a reading.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import time

# DS18B20.py
# 2016-04-25
# Public Domain

# Typical reading
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 : crc=41 YES
# 73 01 4b 46 7f ff 0d 10 41 t=23187

while True:

   for sensor in glob.glob("/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-00*/w1_slave"):
      id = sensor.split("/")[5]

      try:
         f = open(sensor, "r")
         data = f.read()
         f.close()
         if "YES" in data:
            (discard, sep, reading) = data.partition(' t=')
            t = float(reading) / 1000.0
            print("{} {:.1f}".format(id, t))
         else:
            print("999.9")

      except:
         pass

   time.sleep(3.0)
```